Whatsapp integration?
Integrating WhatsApp with CiviCRM can greatly enhance communication and outreach efforts. While there is no ready-made extension available for this purpose. How can i integrate whatsapp in civiCrm.

Welcome to SE!  What sort of integration are you looking for?  Maybe describe what you want to achieve with it.

Have you also checked these two threads: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/civicrm-integration-wtih-whatsapp & https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/44752/is-the-civicrm-whatsapp-integration-extension-available-now?
